# Как быть с противоречивыми наследованием и инкапсуляцией?

Tags: java, безопасность, наследование, инкапсуляция

Добрый день. Вот как пример у нас класс в пакете java.com.test;:

**Bank**

```
package java.com.test;

public class BankAccount {
   private int balance;

   public class BankAccount(int balance) {
      this.balance = balance;
   }

   protected int getBalance() {
      return balance;
   }
}
```

Дальше допустим целую иерархию классов. Ну пусть грубо говоря от BankAccount наследуются другие подтипы аккаунтов. В наследниках класса BankAccount должен использоваться метод getBalance(). Всё замечательно, сделаем его protected. Всё бы ничего, но вот допустим я хочу, чтобы никто и никогда не мог посмотреть баланс аккаунта кроме владельца. Но к сожалению моему, protected даёт доступ всем классам наследникам и классам, которые лежат в одноимённом пакете. Т.е. я могу просто создать свой класс, кинуть его в пакет java.com.test и получить доступ к этому методу и соответственно к балансу. Как это лечить?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71072/discussion-on-question-by-prostocoder------).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, вы пали жертвой распространённого заблуждения - рассмотрения инкапсуляции неотрывно от сокрытия. Во-вторых, сокрытие в целом и модификаторы доступа в частности - это не про защиту от злонамеренных хакеров, взламывающих ваш код наследованием. Модификаторы доступа нужны для предотвращения непреднамеренно ошибочного использования объектов. В больших системах бывает сложно уследить, что один объект из сотен, в одном из тысяч возможных состояний программы не нарушает инварианты другого объекта.

Comment: В общем цель их не в том, чтобы защитить данные, а в том чтобы помочь программисту наслаждаться жизнью и не ломать голову, что это за поле?

Comment: В общих чертах да.

Comment: Ну окей, а что всё таки можно сделать против наследования

Comment: Не надо ничего делать против наследования. Кому надо, тот возьмёт рефлексию или агент и обломает любые ваши защиты.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за пояснения смысла инкапсуляции и ответ на вопрос!

Comment: @ProstoCoder прочитайте на досуге про Dependency Injection

Comment: @Санаев ой, пусть он сначала с базовыми принципами ООП разберётся!

Comment: @Санаев спасиб!